# jQuery Mobile Dynamically appended forms inside Accordion

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, button

I have a accordion collapsible done using jQuery Mobile as shown in the image below. Each accordion has dynamically appended 2 textarea and a button. 
[image]

I have set the click event for the button as below.

```
$('.SaveProj').bind('click',function(){
 var mytest = $('#externalNotesMon').val();
 alert(mytest);
});
```

But the value shown in the alert is the value from the first accordion, not the one from the accordion it was clicked from.

Can someone please enlighten me on this issue?

Please find my code as below

```
var projectListStr = "<div data-role='collapsible-set' data-theme='c' data-content-theme='d' id='collabsibleProjectList' data-inset='false'>";
        $.each(projectList,function(index, value){
                LineOneprojectListStr = "<br/><p class='listP2'><strong>Aktivitet </strong>: "+CheckNullToEmptyString(this.ActivityName)+"</p>";
                LineOneprojectListStr +=  "<br/><p class='listP3'><strong>Händelse/Verksamhet</strong>: "+CheckNullToEmptyString(this.EventName)+"</p>";
                projectListStr += "<div data-role='collapsible' class='myset'>";
                projectListStr += "<h3>"+this.ProjectName+"<span class='ui-li-count'>"+checkNullToZero(this.Days[i].EventTimant2)+"</span>"+LineOneprojectListStr+"</h3>";
                FormStr = "<table align='center'>";
                FormStr += "<tr><th>Hours</th><th>Minutes</th></tr>";
                var TimeStr =  new String((this.Days[i].EventTimant2)).split(".");
                FormStr += "<tr><td><input type='number' name='hoursMon' id='hoursMon' value='"+CheckNullEmptyToZero(TimeStr[0])+"'  /> </td><td><input type='number' name='minsMon' id='minsMon' value='"+CheckNullEmptyToZero(TimeStr[0])+"'  /></td></tr>";
                FormStr += "</table>";
                FormStr += "<div data-role='fieldcontain' >";
                FormStr += "<label for='externalNotesMon'>Fakturatext</label>";
                FormStr += "<textarea name='textarea' id='externalNotesMon' style='min-height:120px'>"+CheckNullToEmptyString(this.Days[i].Editext)+"</textarea>";
                FormStr += "</div>";
                FormStr += "<div data-role='fieldcontain'>";
                FormStr += "<label for='internalNotesMon'>Intern Text</label>";
                FormStr += "<textarea name='textarea' id='internalNotesMon' style='min-height:120px' >"+CheckNullToEmptyString(this.Days[i].Edit)+"</textarea>";
                FormStr += "</div>";
                FormStr += " <a href='#' data-icon='check'  class='SaveProj' data-theme='g' data-role='button'>Spara</a>"
                projectListStr +=FormStr;
            projectListStr +=  "</div>";

        });
projectListStr +=  "</div>";
$('#ProjectList').html(projectListStr);
$('#home2').trigger('create');

$('.SaveProj').bind('click',function(){
  var mytest = $('#externalNotesMon').val();
  alert(mytest);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correct behavior because you have 2 textarea's with an id **externalNotesMon**.

On click event button will retrieve first DOM occurrence of an id **#externalNotesMon**, and that is a first textarea.

To fix this use something like this:

```
$('.SaveProj').bind('click',function(){
    // This will look at buttons previous element and inside search for #externalNotesMon
    var mytest = $(this).prev().find('#externalNotesMon').val();
    alert(mytest);
});
```

Comment: I dynamically added the index behind the id of the textarea and when called used the exact id and it worked. Thanks (y)

Answer (score 0):

try `jQuery.on()` that will work also on dynamically added DOM.

```
$('.SaveProj').on('click',function(){
 var mytest = $('#externalNotesMon').val();
 alert(mytest);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Just replicates the same issue. First accordion value is returned when save button in the 2nd accodian is clicked

Comment: @MayuMayooresan may be its because your fields inside second accordion's css is display none...